# In gulp how to log progress in-between calls to pipes

Tags: logging, gulp

I would like to log some output when when one step finishes and another beginsd. Breaking it into separate tasks would be overkill I think.

```
gulp.task("default", function () {
        return tsProject.src()
            .pipe(tsProject())
            .js.pipe(gulp.dest(""))
            //log something here
            .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(""))
            ;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log some random string, you can use [gulp-util 
.log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util)

```
...
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
...
    .js.pipe(gulp.dest(""))
    .on('end', function(){
        gutil.log('stuff happened', 'Really it did', gutil.colors.magenta('123'));
     })
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
...
```

If you want to log the current file name, you can dot that with [gulp-using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-using)

```
...
var using = require('gulp-using');
...
    .js.pipe(gulp.dest(""))
    .pipe(using({prefix:'stuff happened', color:'green'}))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
...
```